# How to make a variable loop itself inside another loop?

Tags: php, html

It might be confusing and a bit difficult. I have a `$fcomm` variable that holds values as an array. This variable `$fcomm` is then assigned to an 'echo div' into another `foreach` loop. What I need is to make `$fcomm` loop itself while it gets assigned and echoed with each `<div>`. Here's the code...Thank you for any comments.

PHP:

```
for ($i2=0; $i2<$rowscheck; $i2++) {

  //FRIEND QUERY COMMENTS
  $fr_com = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE name_main_id = '".$fcom[$i2]."' ORDER BY comm_id ASC ");

  while ($rows_com = mysqli_fetch_array($fr_com)) {
    extract($rows_com); 
    $fcomm[] = $rows_com['comment_main'];
  }

} 

if ($fr_check > 0 ) { 
  foreach ($friends_q2 as $fr_ids) {
    $added_fr = "members/$fr_ids/userImg1.jpg";
    if (!file_exists($added_fr)) { 
      $added_fr =  "members/avatar/avatar.png" ; 
    } 
    echo "
<div id='frslide'>
  <a href='javascript:window_usr($fr_ids)'>
    <img src='".$added_fr."' height='68' width='66' hspace='2' vspace='16' id='fadd'/>
  </a>
  <span style='font-size:12px;position:relative;left:-71px;top:-1px;color:#ffffff; background-image:url(images/back_bar.png);'>&nbsp;".$frnames2."&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div id='frdiv' class='frdiv'>
  <span style='font-size:12px;position:relative; left:-1px;top:72px;color:#ffffff;background-image:url(images/usr_main.png);'>
    &nbsp;<a href='javascript:remusr($fr_ids)'>remove</a>&nbsp;
  </span>
</div>
<div>".$fcomm;  
  }
}
```

`$fcomm` variable holds strings of comments from SQL. So when I add `$fcomm[$i]` or any loop variable to `$fcomm` it yields just single letters from comments - all I need is to make `$fcomm` print whole strings but different ones and the ones that correspond to proper each `<div>`. When I tried to place `$fcomm` in an inside loop  - it prints strings but each string is the same...

Comment: Your code and markup formatting is error prone. Work on indenting  more consistently.

Comment: `extract($rows_com);` is a great way to introduce bugs. Let's not do that.

Comment: @ThiefMaster No probs, it doesn't play a role in here it can be commented out..

Comment: I don't understand what "make a variable loop itself inside another loop" means

Comment: $fcomm should loop through itself while it's placed inside foreach loop like in here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increase the index you're trying to retrieve from the fcomm array.  Note the changes using $j variable.

```
if ($fr_check > 0 ) { 
  $j=0;
  foreach ($friends_q2 as $fr_ids) {
    $added_fr = "members/$fr_ids/userImg1.jpg";
    if (!file_exists($added_fr)) { 
      $added_fr =  "members/avatar/avatar.png" ; 
    } 
    echo "
<div id='frslide'>
  <a href='javascript:window_usr($fr_ids)'>
    <img src='".$added_fr."' height='68' width='66' hspace='2' vspace='16' id='fadd'/>
  </a>
  <span style='font-size:12px;position:relative;left:-71px;top:-1px;color:#ffffff; background-image:url(images/back_bar.png);'>&nbsp;".$frnames2."&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div id='frdiv' class='frdiv'>
  <span style='font-size:12px;position:relative; left:-1px;top:72px;color:#ffffff;background-image:url(images/usr_main.png);'>
    &nbsp;<a href='javascript:remusr($fr_ids)'>remove</a>&nbsp;
  </span>
</div>
<div>".$fcomm[$j];  
    $j++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Great ! I missed $j=0; Works prefect now...Thanks a lot for your help, well done, you deserve lovely award points...Also, thanks guys as usual to the other answers and your help..

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your code or column names etc., you probably need to populate `$fcomm` based on the friend IDs, and then echo out the corresponding comment in the `foreach` loop.

Something like this:

```
for ($i2=0; $i2<$rowscheck; $i2++) {

    //FRIEND QUERY COMMENTS
    $fr_com = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE name_main_id =  
             '".$fcom[$i2]."' ORDER BY comm_id ASC ");

    while ($rows_com = mysqli_fetch_array($fr_com)) {
        extract($rows_com); 
        // populate $fcomm sub-array using the ID used to select 
        // them, i.e. $fcom[$i2]
        $fcomm[ $fcom[$i2] ][] = $rows_com['comment_main'];    
    }
} 

if ($fr_check > 0 ) { 

    foreach ($friends_q2 as $fr_ids) {

        $added_fr = "members/$fr_ids/userImg1.jpg";

        if (!file_exists($added_fr)) { 
            $added_fr =  "members/avatar/avatar.png" ; 

        } 

        echo "<div id='frslide'>...</div>";

        // echo out the right $fcomm depending on the ID, $fr_ids
        foreach ($fcomm[$fr_ids] as $comment) {
            echo '<div>', $comment, '</div>';  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you intend, to be honest. You're populating `$fcomm` with more than one set of data (i.e. via `$i2` as well as putting in the query results). So I don't actually know what the keys should be.

Comment: I've got a table with comments - the comments are queried alongside the divs with each user's pics - the comments should be aligned to the pics in a div. I have proper pics and divs displays but I cannot assign a proper comment to each pic/div. I only succeed in printing one comment or a string of the same comment repeating..

Comment: Maybe you need to set `$fcomm[$fcom[$i2]][] = $rows_com['comment_main'];` as an array of arrays, and then after the `echo "<div></div>";`, have a `foreach ($fcomm[$fr_ids] as $comment) { echo '<div>', $comment, '</div>'; }`. I'm still not entirely sure what you're trying to do, I'm afraid. Will update the answer above with this suggestion though, so it's clearer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daren! I'll mind your code -  It's been sorted out now - Set Sail Media's solution is exactly what I was looking for...cheers.